# Python: read text file into array - unequal row distrubution

Tags: python, arrays, text, slice, data-processing

I need to process a large text file containing information on scientific publications, exported from the ScienceDirect search page. I want to store the data in an array of arrays, so that each paper is an array, and all papers are stored in a larger array.

The good part is that each line corresponds to the value I want to put in the array, and that there is an empty line between papers. The problem is that each paper has a different number of lines associated with it, ranging from 2 to 6. An example of the data would be:

```
[Authors, title, journal, date] 
[(digital object identifier)]
[(link to ScienceDirect website)] 
[Abstract: Abstract] 
[It has been shown ...]

[Authors, title, journal, date] 
[(digital object identifier)]
[(link to ScienceDirect website)]
[Abstract: Abstract] 
[It has been shown ...]
[Keywords]

[Authors, title, journal, date] 
[(digital object identifier)]
```

and so on. The desired data structure would be ArrayAllPapers [ Paper-1 , Paper-2 , ... ,
Paper-n ], where each paper is an array Paper-1 [ author-line , doi-line , etc ]

I am able to read the file into python line by line as an array, but then run up against the problem of slicing the list based on a list item (in this case '\n'). I have found solutions to this problem for datasets with equal line spacing for objects, most of them written for lists, but none that work for unequal distribution. Perhaps I need to write to the text file first to fill in 'missing' rows to create an equal distribution?

I am still learning to work with Python (some experience with MatLab), so please excuse me if there is an obvious solution for this. I have tried finding a solution but have come up empty.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

For reference, the code I use now to enter the text file into an array:

```
import re, numpy 
with open("test-abstracts-short.txt", "r") as text: 
    array = [] 
    for line in text: 
        array.append(line)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried/your code?

Comment: of course! since I am stuck at the beginning trying to find the right approach, I thought the code might not add much, but here's the bit of code that I use to put the rows into an array:

import re, numpy

`with open("test-abstracts-short.txt", "r") as text:
    array = []
    for line in text:
        array.append(line)`

I import regular expressions because I've been trying to make something with that, but haven't succeeded. 
Also, I am happy to do more research and learning myself, if only someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Also, as you can see from my profile, this is my first question on the forum, please excuse any formatting/etiquette mistakes I may make (perhaps like posting code in a comment? it doesnt seem to format properly into lines, perhaps I should add it to the main post?)

Comment: Better to add it to the question, so that it gets properly formatted/indented

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, added it at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to skip blank lines, the easiest thing to do is to check if a line is blank.

```
x = []
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    temp_list = []
    for line in f:
        if line.strip(): #line is not blank
            temp_list.append(line)
        else: #line is blank, i.e., it contains only newlines and/or whitespace
            if temp_list: #check if temp_list contains any items
                x.append(temp_list)
            temp_list = []
```

Comment: Fantastic, that solves it! Beautiful to read a piece of code and suddenly see  a solution to a problem that you couldn't see yourself. This makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If first lines are mandatory, you can try to parse them and for each article create structure like this `{'author': 'Name', 'digital_object_identifier': 'Value'}` and so on.

Than you can try to parse most common keywords and append them as fields. So your article woild be like this:
`{'author': 'Name', 'digital_object_identifier': 'Value', 'keyword1': 'Value', 'keyword2': 'Value', 'keyword3': 'Value'}`.

Than you can add all unparsed keywords in some specific field (to do not lose data):
`{'author': 'Name', 'digital_object_identifier': 'Value', 'keyword1': 'Value', 'keyword2': 'Value', 'keyword3': 'Value', 'other_keys': {'key': 'value'}}`.

So, in other words, you can split your document om mandatory and non-mandatory fields.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To see if I understand it correctly, you mean to create an array from each first line of an article, and then create fields for each possible data type for an article, and to then fill these fields based on keywords. I think this approach will run up against the fact that the fields are not labeled (in the data they are simply strings without obvious delimiters). This is in fact not a problem for me, it's okay if the row containing the authors, title, etc, is a single string as a value inside an array, the problem is how to create separate entries for each paper

Comment: To clarify, each row can be put into a single value of an array 'as is', but I would like to have all rows between paragraphs (or '\n\n') to be part of one array. 
Also, I would upvote to thank you, but I don't have the required level yet :-)